# Module '/node_modules/rxjs/observable/TimerObservable' has no exported member 'TimerObservable' in Angular 6

Tags: angular6, rxjs6

While migrating application from Angular 5 to Angular 6 getting below error,

```
Module '/node_modules/rxjs/observable/TimerObservable' has no exported member 'TimerObservable'.
```

Code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { TimerObservable } from 'rxjs/observable/TimerObservable';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class TimerTestScv {

    static fetchTimer(interval: number, initialDelay: number): Observable<number>         
    {
       return TimerObservable.create(initialDelay, interval);
    }
}
```

rxjs package used:

```
"rxjs": "^6.2.2",
```

Answer (score 3):

From RxJS 6 onwards, `TimerObservable` has been replaced with `timer`. Use the following as a replacement:

```js
import { timer } from 'rxjs';

// start at time 1s and tick every 2s
let myTimer = timer(1000, 2000);

const subscription = myTimer.subscribe(() => {
    /* Do stuff here */
})
...
subscription.unsubscribe()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `timer` instead of `TimerObservable`

> All observable classes
>   (https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/tree/5.5.8/src/observable) [have
>   been removed from v6](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#observable-classes), in favor of existing or new operators that
>   perform the same operations as the class methods.